# A bash script that creates a file, writes into the it then searches and replaces words in the file

Tags: bash, loops

new at this, so any suggestions would be great!

I'm trying to create a file, input the contents of the file,show the file and finally then search and replace words in that file and display the contents again.

The file should contain the following:

```
Write a bash script
To show off 
Your scripting skills
Then show the results
```

Search and replace the words “Your” with “My” and the word “Then” with “Now”

So far Ive got:

```
#Check if the file exits and create if not (im not sure if there is a better way to do this)
if [ ! -e "NewFile.txt" ]; then
    touch NewFile.txt
fi

#Ask user for input
echo "Input the content of the file:"

#Display the file the first time
cat NewFile.txt

#load what's in the file into an array. 
not sure what to put here 

#search and replace “Your” with “My” and the word “Then” with “Now”
not sure what to put here 


#display the file after words have been replaced
cat NewFile.txt
```

Comment: It seems like the part you say you're not sure of is the whole point of the exercise.

Comment: Why do you need an array? You should be able to do this using `sed`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @Barmar with an array: `while read -ra ar;do case ${ar[0]} in Your ) echo My ${ar[@]:1};; Then ) echo Now ${ar[@]:1};;*)echo ${ar[@]};;esac;done`

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I'm not saying it can't be done with an array, just that it's simpler with `sed`. So unless this is an assignment about working with arrays, it seems like an unnecessarily complicated way to do it.

Comment: thanks @F. Hauri - Give Up GitHub
I'll have to look up exactly what you mean though because it looks a bit complicated. I thought for the search and replace it could be just one line. Im not sure what the wildcard is for.

Comment: What did you intend when you wrote "writes into the it" in the title?

Comment: @Wyck write lines from user input into the file

Comment: A lot of the steps proposed are unnecessary. You don't generally _need_ to create files before you can write to them -- when you open for write with `>` or `>>`, that uses the `O_CREAT` flag by default, causing the file to be created if it doesn't already exist; no `touch` or anything else needed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for that, i thought there probably was a better way of doing it alright. so would 
echo "Write this to a file." > NewFile.txt be the best way?
Or is a way for user input to write directly to file?
read "Enter your text: " user_input
echo "$user_input" > NewFile.txt

I know this is sort of going off topic now, not sure if its against the rules or anything. Again I'm just starting out at this, so let me know if anything isnt allowed

Comment: Usually [I'd avoid `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo), and there are some extra flags you want to pass to `read` (so in code I was writing it might look more like`IFS= read -p "Enter your text: " -r user_input && printf '%s\n' "$user_input" >input.txt` -- on the read command, the `-r` stops backslashes in your text from being eaten, and the `IFS=` stops leading and trailing whitespace from being stripped)

Comment: (comments are a lot less restrictive than Q&A proper here in terms of the rules -- one needs to be polite to people, and eventually someone might decline to answer follow-up questions / tangents, but it's way more acceptable to ask follow-up questions in a comment than it is to edit a question after it's answered to expand its scope; this way, worst thing you'll get is someone wandering off, or asking you to expand your tangent into a whole new well-formed question -- just note that comments are transient and open to deletion; anything that needs to be stable long-term should be Q&A).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

```
sed -i 's/Your/My/g' input.txt && sed -i 's/Then/Now/g' input.txt
```

Which replace the first wort with the second word, editing the file. I have two commands to achieve it, one is for the first replace and the second is for the second replace, separated via `&&`.

Comment: Thank you that worked for search and replace, appreciate the explanation too :)